# Handle multiple Intents on single Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I have three activities. On `Activity` One (Navigation Menu), I have a simple `ClickListener` to start `Activity` Two.

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
intent3.putExtra("from", "BaseActivity");
startActivity(intent3);
finish();
break;
```

On `Actvity` Three I have some data that I need on `Activity` Two. So I put the data inside the `Bundle` like this:

```
//send Data to Setting Activity
Intent mIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString("from", "SettingsActivity");
mBundle.putSerializable("spinnerHashTagItems", (Serializable) spinner_HashTagItem);
mBundle.putSerializable("spinnerUserItem", (Serializable) spinner_UserItem);
mBundle.putBoolean("isCheckedHashTag", isCheckedHashTag);
mBundle.putBoolean("isCheckedHashTagUser", isCheckedHashTagUser);
mBundle.putBoolean("isCheckedAllFromUser", isCheckedAllFromUser);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

So if I start the `Activity` Two I only get the `Intent` from the first `Activity` but not from the Third:

```
//get loadet Settings from StartActivity
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    //do nothing
}

Bundle bundle1 = getIntent().getExtras();
spinner_HashTagItems.clear();
spinner_HashTagItems = (List<String>) bundle1.getSerializable("spinner_HashTagItem");
spinner_userItems.clear();
spinner_userItems = (List<String>) bundle1.getSerializable("spinner_userItem");
chbox_hashTag.setChecked(bundle1.getBoolean("chbox_hashTag"));
chbox_hashTagUser.setChecked(bundle1.getBoolean("chbox_hashTagUser"));
chbox_allFromUser.setChecked(bundle1.getBoolean("chbox_allFromUser"));
```

I went with the debugger trough the `Activity` Two and get the `Bundle` from the `Activity` One. How can I get the `Bundle` from `Activity` Three?

Comment: where is ur `startActivity(mIntent);` ?

Comment: I dont want to start the Activity. I need only the data. Activity One is the StartActivity, that loads the Settings on Start and give the Data to SettingActvity (Activity Two). I dont want to start the Settings on the start of the App.

Comment: You have some data you want to send from Activity One via Activity Two to the Activity Three, right?

Comment: you should call startActivity to send data from Activit to another activity.

Comment: No I want to send my Data from Activity One to Activity Two, but I get the Data from Activity Three.

Comment: " So if I start the activity two I only get the Intent from the first Activity but not from the third". You are only calling startActivity() with intent3, if you never send mIntent how the heck do you exect to receive its data

Comment: Sorry, my bad. t I get the Data from Actvity One, (the ClickListener) witout Data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)` to start your `SettingsActivity` from `StartActivity`.

Handle the result in `StartActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_YOU_USED_TO_START_SETTINGS_ACTIVITY) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //read the data from the Intent and prepare the Bundle for Activity Two
    }
}
}
```